# Help with plurals (and maybe more)

Tags: grammaticality

I'm struggling with a line of text.

I'm trying to write an instruction for someone to add up the lowest balance/s in multiple bank accounts in a monthly period and enter the total into a text field. And it needs to be in very plain English.

I've currently got:

Add the lowest balance in each account last month and enter the total

Does that make sense? Should it be 'balances' instead?

Thanks.

Comment: You've got to add A to B, or **add up all the As**. But you also need 'the lowest balance [not 'balances'] in each account' to preserve meaning. As 358 answers, you need to rephrase.

Answer (score 2):

Find the lowest balance there was last month in each of the accounts and enter the sum of all those balances in a text field.

Answer (score 1):

"Take each account's lowest balance for the month, add them together, then enter the total in [describe text field]"